# Duplicate with a bounty

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bounty

I found a question that is a duplicate (almost exact), asked by the same person twice.  The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938835/very-slow-query-execution-time) had one answer, and the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040705/extremely-slow-select-query-on-mysql) (duplicate) was asked 6 days later.  Since the owner put a bounty on it before anyone noticed it was a duplicate I can't flag the question as a duplicate.  It was pointed out in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040705/extremely-slow-select-query-on-mysql#28195148) that this question is a duplicate.  What is the proper action to take for this question and the "answer"?

Comment: 1) Comment, wait until the bounty expires, and then close 2) Close the original question as a duplicate 3) Request the questions to be merged

Comment: I would probably flag > other and explain the situation.